# Get OCP containers information

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I'm trying to get some information of all the containers running in a namespace:

```
oc get pods -n my-namespace -o custom-columns=NAME:.spec.containers[*].name,CPU:.spec.containers[*].resources.requests.cpu
```

This works well, but for a pod with multiple containers, I get the information separated by comma:

```
container-1,container-2           500m,500m
```

How can I adjust the command to get the expected below?

```
container-1           500m
container-2           500m
```